# How to switch default forum vocabulary?

Tags: 7, nodes

I'm using the Drupal forum and advanced_forum modules, and I have been struggling with how to set the default vocabulary used by the core Drupal forum module.

I have migrated forum nodes and comments from a Drupal 6 to 7 site without a hitch. The views that come with the forum modules work fine, but I can't seem to change the Panel page that does the heavy lifting.

The forum module was trying to use a vocabulary called Tags, so I uninstalled it, deleted Tags, and re-installed it, and it creates a taxonomy called "Forums". The problem is, I already have a vocabulary with that name.

Note I have correctly set the proper term reference for the taxonomy_forums field. Again, the issue is 1) the core forum module is trying to use the wrong vocabulary; 2) The panels supplied by advanced forum are also using the incorrect vocabulary, and there's no way to change it using the UI.

I'd settle for a manual database update at this point.

Comment: Have a look at my answer to [this question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/177018/how-can-i-replace-the-forums-vocabulary-forums-with-my-existing-vocabulary-t/177021#177021), which seems like a variation (not a duplicate) of your question. I think my answer may give you some more ideas you may want to try (to avoid the manual database update you are considering). Curious to hear if there is anything in that answer that helped you for this question also ...

Comment: Yes I did thanks, but unfortunately, unless I am able to solve the panels issue or somehow find a way to edit the dB manually, I'm out of luck right now, and would have to re-migrate the data using the new taxonomy field.